# python2 and pandas: get all occurrence of day during a year in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a large number of rows dataframe(df_m) as below.

I want to plot the number of occurrence of day for years(2010-2017) of `date_m` column in the dataframe. Since the year range of `date_m` is from 2010-2017, and sometimes the day is more than one time, for example, `2010-07-26` there are two times, so the occurrence of `2010-07-26` is `2`, but sometimes, the day have no data, for example `2010-7-21` is `0`, I want to count the occurrence of days during a whole year(from 2010-2017), when the day is in the dataframe, and count the occurrence, when is not in the dataframe, the occurrence is 0, please check the dataframe form as below. And Finally want to the days occurrence every month for years as shown the following figure.

Could you give me some hints how to do it, thanks!

```
 db  num           date_a     date_m   date_c zip_b  zip_a
0   old HKK10032    2010-07-14  2010-07-26  NaT NaN NaN
1   old HKK10109    2011-07-14  2011-09-15  NaT NaN NaN
2   old HNN10167    2012-07-15  2012-08-09  NaT 177-003 NaN
3   old HKK10190    2013-07-15  2013-09-02  NaT NaN NaN
4   old HKK10251    2014-07-16  2014-05-02  NaT NaN NaN
5   old HKK10253    2015-07-16  2015-05-01  NaT NaN NaN
6   old HNN10275    2017-07-16  2017-07-18  2010-07-18  1070062 NaN
7   old HKK10282    2017-07-16  2017-08-16  NaT NaN NaN
8   old HKK10032    2010-07-14  2010-07-26  NaT NaN NaN
9   old HKK10109    2011-07-14  2011-09-15  NaT NaN NaN
....
```

The dataframe form I want to get

```
    2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017
1       0     1     0     1     0     2     1     0
2       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3       0     0     1     0     0     2     0     0
4       0    16    14    47    37    37    26    31
5       0    18    11    29    29    24    16    23
6       0    13     8    31    33    24    16    32
7       0    14    31    25    17    21    24    70
8       0    16    25    14    21    27    35    59
9       0    16    10    22    16    31    54    42
10      0    15    11    22    37    48    53    29
11      0    13    10    39    43    41    28    36
12      0     5     7    51    44    30    34    24
13      0    10    13    65    17    30    32    48
14      0    15    26    22    27    31    25    85
15      0    22    22    38    31    30    36    71
16      0    22    19    41    36    33    50    41
17      0    14    19    32    34    43    55    27
18      0    12    17    32    54    37    22    32
19      0     7    14    76    41    32    24    36
20      1     7    22    55    34    30    39    57
21      0    14    39    50    28    26    31   100
22      0    20    32    28    35    30    45    80
23      0    18    19    46    26    31    59    52
24      0    12    20    33    47    59    45    51
25      0    16    22    55    49    48    47    40
26      0    13    17    77    43    40    45    50
27      0    18    33    70    37    39    45    85
28      0    17    34    59    36    46    58   111
29      0    23    27    53    36    39    70    91
30      0    28    37    55    45    52    82    77
..    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
337    19    37    53    40    38    27    55     0
338    29    18    61    25    34    33    69     0
339    18    13    21    27    34    52    54     0
340    17    14    38    33    44    48    48     0
341    14    15    22    48    43    36    38     0
342    13    10    28    49    35    31    36     0
343    12    21    62    33    23    31    43     0
344    20    37    45    29    31    41    45     0
345    15    26    50    19    27    47    76     0
346    24    22    29    27    36    63    71     0
347    16    14    38    43    41    51    33     0
348    13    19    46    52    38    49    34     0
349    22    19    42    46    30    50    49     0
350    17    28    75    54    42    40    42     0
351    22    41    61    34    44    36    44     0
352    23    34    55    42    37    57    79     0
353    30    34    51    45    38    65    81     0
354    25    32    49    57    43    59    61     0
355    22    29    64    50    53    66    62     0
356    24    34    62    54    46    64    66     0
357    19    39    76    47    49    74    79     0
358    29    33    63    44    46    51    83     0
359    28    24    53    38    55    49    82     0
360    26    35    58    46    42    66    63     0
361    27    35    73    32    38    72    70     0
362    21    27    64    42    41    60    66     0
363    23    28    52    47    44    39    61     0
364    16    16    40    27    17    32    67     0
365     0     1    31     0    14    13    38     0
366     0     0     1     0     0     0    17     0

[366 rows x 8 columns]
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1 = df.groupby('date_b')['date_b'].count()
        .reindex(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31', freq='D'), fill_value=0)
```

EDIT:

Need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and [`day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html) and aggregate [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html). Then create new [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) original, last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
df['date_m'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_m'])
df1 = df.groupby([df['date_m'].dt.year, df['date_m'].dt.day])['date_m'].count()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2010, 2018), range(1, 32)])
df1 = df1.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
df1 = df1.unstack(0)
```

---

```
print (df1)
    2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017
1      0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
2      0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
3      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
5      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
6      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
7      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
8      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
9      0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
11     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
12     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
13     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
14     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
15     0     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
16     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
17     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
18     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
19     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
20     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
21     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
22     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
23     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
24     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
25     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
26     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
27     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
28     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
29     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
30     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
31     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

df1.plot()
```

EDIT: Need [`dayofyear`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofyear.html):

```
df['date_m'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_m'])
df1 = df.groupby([df['date_m'].dt.year, df['date_m'].dt.dayofyear])['date_m'].count()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2010, 2018), range(1, 367)])
df1 = df1.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
df1 = df1.unstack(0)
print (df1)
     2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017
1       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
5       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
6       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
7       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
8       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
9       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
10      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
11      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
12      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
...
...

df1.plot()
```

Comment: There is some problem if use `df1.plot()` ?

Comment: thanks @jezrael, if I used the df1.plot(), the figure is x-axis is (2010, 2011, 2012,2013,2014, 2015,2016,2017), and y-axis is number of occurrence of eveyday.  Actually, I want to plot the 8 lines(one line is a year, for example 2010,2011) in the same figure, x-axis is the days or months of year, and y-aixs is the number occurrence.

Comment: Ok, now understand. Give me some time.

Comment: Please check edited answer. If need DataFrame by years and months, instead `dt.day`  use `df.month` and change `range` in `MultiIndex.from_product`.

Comment: please check it, I hope I understadn what you need.

Comment: hi  @jezrael  thanks for your answer. I think there are some missing information that I explained. I want to show everyday occurrence for a year. The day range is (1-366 or 365). I used your code just used the day(1,31) for year, not the whole years days, 365/366. Could you revise you code for this, please!

Comment: Please check edited answer, only is removed `dt.day` and `mux` was changed by date range.

Comment: thanks, I think there is different,  I have done a little change based on your code, please check my question.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.DatFrame.groupby()` and `pandas.DatFrame.count()` can be used as:

**Code:**

```
df.groupby('date_b').date_b.count()
```

**Test Code:**

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    date_a      date_b
    2010-07-14  2010-07-26
    2011-07-14  2011-09-15
    2012-07-15  2012-08-09
    2013-07-15  2013-09-02
    2014-07-16  2014-05-02
    2015-07-16  2015-05-01
    2017-07-16  2017-07-18
    2017-07-16  2017-08-16
    2010-07-14  2010-07-26
    2011-07-14  2011-09-15"""), header=1)

print(df.groupby('date_b').date_b.count())
```

**Results:**

```
date_b
2010-07-26    2
2011-09-15    2
2012-08-09    1
2013-09-02    1
2014-05-02    1
2015-05-01    1
2017-07-18    1
2017-08-16    1
Name: date_b, dtype: int64
```

**For a single year with zeros included:**

To get the zeros for a year you can reindex as:

```
counts = df.groupby('date_b').date_b.count()
year = counts.reindex(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31', freq='D')).fillna(0)
```

Comment: thanks @Stephen Rauch, what about someday is not in this dataframe, for example 2010-07-25, how to count it? I want to count the number of days in a year, if the day is not in dataframe is 0.

Comment: There is nothing to count.  What do you expect the final data to look like?

Comment: I want to plot the occurrence of days for a  whole year (from 2010-2017), for example year:2010, 1-365(leap is 366or not) days, and count the occurrence of  days in the dataframe. if the day is not in dataframe, the occurrence is 0.

Comment: yes,  but I just want to plot the format  as shown figure.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('date_m').date_m.count().reindex(pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2017-12-31',freq='D')).fillna(0)
```

Comment: thanks @Scott Boston for your kind comments. Could you tell me how to plot days occurrence of  years(from 2010, 2017) in the same figure